# Records difference in three tables - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables `Tab1`, `Tab2` and `Tab3` with almost same structre (in MS Access). But `Tab2` and `Tab3` have a few more columns than `Tab1`.

`Tab2` and `Tab3` are exactly same structure. Following are the joining keys

```
col1
col2
col3
```

Basically `Tab1` records should tally with `Tab2` and `Tab3` together.
If I need to get the missing records in `Tab2` and `Tab3` when compare to `Tab1` what could be the efficient way

Appreciate your response

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the keys, here is a good approach:

```
select col1, sum(isTab1) as numTab1, sum(isTab2) as numTab2, sum(isTab3) as numTab3
from ((select col1 as col, 1 as isTab1, 0 as isTab2, 0 as isTab3 from tab1
      ) union all
      (select col2, 0 as isTab1, 1 as isTab2, 0 as isTab3 from tab2
      ) union all
      (select col3, 0 as isTab1, 0 as isTab2, 1 as isTab3 from tab3
      )
     ) t
group by col
having sum(isTab1)*sum(isTab2)*sum(isTab3) <> 1
```

This returns each of the key values and tells you which tables they are in and not in, for keys that are not in all three tables.  As a bonus, this will also tell you if any of the tables have duplicate keys.

Comment: Hi Gordon, This doesn't seems to supported in MS Access

Comment: @shabar . . . All of these constructs *are* supported by MS Access.  What is your error message?  What version of Access are you using?

Comment: Hi Gordon, It's my bad. There was an issue in my script syntax. However in this it's not checking key combination between tables. Isn't it. It's just individual key value existence is checking among tables  cheers  Shabar

Comment: I came up with below query. Can that results be achieved by changing your query    ` SELECT TT.Tcol1, TT.Tcol2, TT.Tcol3
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Tcol1, Tcol3, Tcol2 FROM Tab2 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT Tcol1, Tcol3, Tcol2, RuleCode FROM Tab3 )  AS WP 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Tab1.T1col1, Tab1.T1col3, Tab1.T1col2 
FROM Tab1)  AS TT 
ON (WP.Tcol2 = TT.T1col2) 
AND (WP.Tcol3 = TT.T1col3) 
AND (WP.Tcol1 = TT.T1col1)
WHERE WP.Tcol1 IS NULL
AND WP.Tcol2 IS NULL
AND WP.Tcol3 IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

usually you would SELECT FROM tab1 LEFT JOINing the tab2 and tab3 LEFT JOINed together. That way you will get ALL records from tab1. When there are some missing records in tab2 and tab3 there will be nulls. You can check for nulls in the WHERE clause

So, the query would look similar to this one (please note the brackets - it is a requirement for ms-access):

```
SELECT * FROM
tab1 LEFT JOIN (tab2 LEFT JOIN tab3 ON tab2.col1 = tab3.col1 AND tab2.col2 = tab3.col2)
ON tab1.col1 = tab2.col1 AND tab1.col2 = tab2.col2 
WHERE tab2.col1 Is Null;
```

Comment: Hi Cha, Thanks for you reply. In the solution If I swap tab 2 and tab 2 as below I get different number of records. Basically Tab2 has more number of records than Tab3
How can this be happened. SELECT * FROM
tab1 LEFT JOIN (tab3 LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab2.col1 = tab3.col1 AND tab2.col2 = tab3.col2)
ON tab1.col1 = tab3.col1 AND tab1.col2 = tab3.col2 
WHERE tab3.col1 Is Null;

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tab1 LEFT JOIN (tab3 LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab2.col1 = tab3.col1 AND tab2.col2 = tab3.col2) ON tab1.col1 = tab3.col1 AND tab1.col2 = tab3.col2 WHERE tab3.col1 Is Null;  `

Comment: when you swap tables around you would find the records that are present in one table but not in another. In you case you just found records that are present in tab2 but missing in tab3

Comment: I got that point. Thanks for that. But basically here what I am trying to accomplish here is, when combine 'Tab2' and 'Tab3'
and then compare that with 'Tab1' and check what are missing in that combination ('Tab2' and 'Tab3'). Hope this helps to clear out the situation

Comment: this will do: `SELECT * FROM tab2 LEFT JOIN (tab3 LEFT JOIN tab1 ON tab3.col1 = tab1.col1 AND tab3.col2 = tab1.col2) ON tab2.col1 = tab1.col1 AND tab2.col2 = tab1.col2 WHERE tab1.col1 Is Null;`